# Partial fraction expansion of inverse differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-fractions, differential-operators

I don't find it obvious that an inverse differential operator can be decomposed into partial fractions like ordinary polynomials and the result obtained is same as if the whole operator is operated on a function.

The book says:-

1)If $$y_{p} = \frac{1}{P(D)}Q(D)$$, then the inverse operator can also be expanded into partial fractions just as if it were an ordinary polynomial.

2)Applying each member of a partial fraction expansion of $$\frac{1}{P(D)}$$ to $$Q(x)$$ and adding the results will give the same answer as will applying the orignal operator to Q.

I don't see why this is true.

Additional information :- 
P(D) is a polynomial in D, the differential operator, applied on y.
The original equation is : $$P(D)y = Q(x)$$ and we seek to find a particular solution of this equation.

Example : 
$$
y_{p} =\frac{1}{(D-1)(D-2)}Q(x)  = \frac{-1}{(D-1)}Q(x) +\frac{1}{(D-2)}Q(x)$$
[From Elementary Differential Equations - Morris Tenenbaum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEMI5.png)
and [From the same book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDVrB.png)

Comment: Could you include the text in the image, transcripted directly into your post?  Otherwise, your question is unclear to those who are cautious about clicking any ol' link.  (I ask that only because I think it is doable.  You can use `$y_p = \frac 1{P(D)}Q(x)$` to format the  equation.

Comment: @amWhy Sorry, I did not mean to dismiss/ignore your comment. I often upload images where users don't have the rep to do so themselves, please advise if I shouldn't. I certainly agree that posting images, which could be written out, indicates a level of bone idleness on the part of the OP.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  I've done the same thing many times in the past, and there are many occasions where it is entirely valid to do so (geometry sketch) to do so.  I have no doubt that you meant well.  So I can not really fault you.  Just take it as an FYI only, for consideration.

Comment: @Harsh  It seems you're asking for solutions to 6 problems? You've attached two problems in your first link, and 4 more problems in your second link.  Keep it to one (at most two, as in your first link) problems per question post on MSE.  By definition, asking 6 questions in one post is "too broad".

Comment: @amWhy Sorry for my tardiness in typing out the problem. I was working around LaTex for the first time. I am only asking about the notion of partial fraction expansion of inverse differential operators and not answer to 6 problems. The first image contains two points related to how to use partial fraction and the second one contains an example with 4 equations marked c,d,e,d. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious or not, it's true. Except of course writing the inverse of an operator as a reciprocal is hideous.

Consider an example: $$\frac{2}{t^2-1}=\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t+1}.$$

We want to verify on this basis that $$2(D^2-I)^{-1}=(D-I)^{-1}-(D+I)^{-1}.$$ There's no problem with the factorization $D^2-I=(D-I)(D+I)=(D+I)(D-I)$. So
$$((D-I)^{-1}-(D+I)^{-1})\frac12(D^2-I)=\frac12((D+I)-(D-I))=I,$$which says that $(D-I)^{-1}-(D+I)^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\frac12(D^2-I)$.

**Of course** that's a little "informal", to put it charitably, since these things are not even invertible, having non-trivial  nullspaces. If you were to apply this to solving $\frac12(y''-y)=f$, you'd want to say the general solution is the general  solution to  $y'-y=f$, including the "$c_1$", minus the general solution to $y'+y=f$, including the "$c_2$".

One could clean up the math a bit by calling $P(D)^{-1}$ a one-sided inverse, and/or regarding $P(D)^{-1}f$ as a *set of* functions. I'm not going to worry about that - it gives the right answer when I do an example, and what's above is good enough to convince me that's  not just a coincidence.

**Edit:** I worried about it. This may be a better way to put the argument: Say $g_1=(D+1)^{-1}f$ and $g_2=(D-I)^{-1}f$, so $(D+I)g_1=f=(D-I)g_2$. Then $$\frac12(D^2-I)(g_1-g_2)=\frac12(D-I)(D+I)(g_2-g_1)=\frac12((D+I)f-(D-I)f)=f.$$

**Note** Although what's above is correct, I don't see the point to it in solving differential equations - seems to me just using $(D^2-I)^{-1}=(D-I)^{-1}(D+I)^{-1}$ is simpler, no need for the partial fractions, and also easier to justify. There's nothing unclean about the following:

Note that $y''-y=z'-z$, if $z=y'+y$. So to solve $y''-y=f$, first solve $z'-z=f$ and then solve $y'+y=z$.